# Get set properties

Tags: c#, get, set

So im trying to use the get / set properties on C# but I cant get my code to work ( it crashes my console app )

This is my textHandler.cs file as you can see the public static void method WriteInfo is using get / set properties but it crashes my app..

```
class TextHandler
{
    public static void WriteInfo(String text)
    {
        var consoleText = new Text();
        consoleText.text = text;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        Console.WriteLine(consoleText);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
    public static void WriteError(String text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
    public static void WriteSuccess(String text)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    }
    public static void WriteText(String text, ConsoleColor color)
    {
    }
}
public class Text
{
    public String text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I call that method

```
TextHandler.WriteInfo("New client with version : " + message + " | current version : " + version);
```

If I remove that line the app doesnt crash anymore, dont know what Im doing wrong since I dont get any error.
Also if this is a bad method to do this please tell me I would like to improve
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code that creates infinit recursion is:

```
public String text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
        }
    }
```

In set you assign `this.text = value` to itself, creating infinit recursion, so `StackOverflow` soon or later.

Seems that you do no need a field, so change your code to:

```
 public String Text {get;set} //PROPERTIES ARE UPPERCASE BY MS STANDART
```

Comment: Yeah, also, OP shouldn't even have this class. Why create a separate class that just holds a string?

Comment: Yes, what you said is working but I never get the String text displayed, I just get "ServerApp.text" instead (serverApp is the namespace ) Any idea?

Comment: may be property name Text is not so good, you may chnage it. In your case it may be enough to do: ServerApp.text t = new Server.App.text(); text.text..

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate the "backing" field from the public property:

```
public class Text
{
    private string text;

    public String TheText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, `TheText` is the a "badly named" public property and `text` is the backing field.  At the moment, your code is addressing the same field for both, causing recursion. Usually the convention would be to have a capital property `Text` and a lowercase backing field `text`.

However, in your code you have named the class `Text` so it is confusing to address `text.Text`.

Comment: Yes, what you said is working but I never get the String text displayed, I just get "ServerApp.text" instead (serverApp is the namespace ) Any idea?

Comment: To get the value you would then need: `Console.WriteLine(consoleText.TheText);`.  This will `Get` the value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create the "Text" class.  Just pass the string to Console.WriteLine.  Also, you didn't specify the nature of the application.  This will work fine in a console app, but may not work for a web application or other app that is not bound to the SdtOut

Answer (score 1):

So,
You are setting the into the property that is calling again the set method until you get a StackOverflow exception.

To avoid this try this

```
public class Text
{
    string _text = null;
    public String text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Or empty get set methods

```
public class Text
{
    public  string text { get; set; }
}
```